Samba AD-DC and sudo with password
Upgraded to latest on Ubuntu 24.04.1:samba-ad-dc/noble,noble,now 2:4.19.5+dfsg-4ubuntu9.
Now I am not able to password auth a sudo group member if it is also a domain user while nsswitch.conf is configured with winbind.
In auth.log I get:
pam_krb5(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=DOMAIN\user uid=xxxxxx euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/2 ruser=DOMAIN\user rhost=
pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [DOMAIN\user]

in log.DOMAINwb:
auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:844(gensec_start_mech)
Starting GENSEC mechanism gse_krb5
source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:425(fill_mem_keytab_from_system_keytab)
source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:425: krb5_kt_start_seq_get failed (Permission denied)

No file read access for winbindd for system keytab/etc/krb5.keytab
I can add that there are no apparmor DENIED cases.
ps -aux shows:
root 5101 0.0 0.3 169692 63488 ? Ss 13:22 0:01 /usr/sbin/winbindd -D --option=server role check:inhibit=yes --foreground

While in LOG:
source3/librpc/crypto/gse_krb5.c:425: krb5_kt_start_seq_get failed (Permission denied)

and ls- -l shows:
-rw------- 1 root root 6917 Nov 1 16:32 /etc/krb5.keytab

There is no winbind or samba user and I have presumed that samba-ad-dc is run by root that has rw access to keytab file. One could add group access to keytab if one would know who is running AD-DC winbindd sub process of reading keytab into cache.
This only happens in AD-DC system. All other servers happily do password auth for sudo.

The right asnwer is:
chmod 0640 on /etc/krb5.keytab to:
-rw-r----- 1 root root 6917 Nov  1 16:32 /etc/krb5.keytab

and logins work!
